# Kentico - SessionManager.IsUserOnline Sometimes returns false

Tags: asp.net, kentico, kentico-12

Are there any known issues with SessionManager.IsUserOnline() ?

We got following code on a class and sometimes it returns false eventhough the user is logged in.

```
bool userIsOnline = SessionManager.IsUserOnline(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, 100, true);
```

It only happens sometimes so pretty hard to debug what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use SessionManager.  Use MembershipContext instead.